# On Key press cancel change event of text box and on button click trigger change event of text box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to cancel change event of a text box on keypress then I want to trigger it on button click. 
This is example of my HTML

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    var target = '#test';
    $(target).on("change");
    $(target).focus();
    $(target).val('HELLO').trigger('change');
});

$("#test").change(function(event) {
    alert($(this).val())
});
$('#test').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       $(this).off("change");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" value="BUTTON1" />
```

but it is not firing change event.

Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aanair08/0624eq86/)**

Comment: Remove     event.stopImmediatePropagation(); Just updated the fiddle and found working.

Comment: No, not firing change event can you please share fiddle link

Comment: It's not. Try this scenario: First click button, -alert- then, sometype . Ye is seems good. But then click button, no alert. I think problem is here. @AnupYadav

Comment: yes, same event was not added in function param.

Comment: and why u want trigger change event with button? What you want? If you just alert the value, refer to function.

Comment: Actually my real scenario is  on key press enter call ajax request and display some suggestions and clicking on suggestion set value to text box and call its change event

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
                var target='#test';
        $(target).on("change",changeText($(target)));
        $(target).focus();
        $(target).val('HELLO').trigger('change');
});

function changeText($this) {
     alert($this.val())
}
$('#test').on('keypress', function (event) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $(this).off("change");
});
```

event was not in function param and trying to use propogation https://jsfiddle.net/0624eq86/20/

Comment: I tried that . But change event was not working when i type on text box and hit button .
https://jsfiddle.net/aanair08/0624eq86/14/

Comment: Actually my real scenario is get on key press enter call ajax request and display some suggestions  and clicking on suggestion set value to text box and call its change event

Comment: Button click and key press is  globally written function and change event is separate for each page. I am seeking  a solution that resolve it globally.

Answer (score 1):

i think you forget add "event" in javascript code

replace :

```
$('#test').on('keypress', function() {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $(this).off("change");
});
```

with:

```
$('#test').on('keypress', function(event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $(this).off("change");
});
```

Comment: I try that also. But it is not fire change event of text box.
https://jsfiddle.net/aanair08/0624eq86/14/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(val){
    alert(val);
}
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    var target = '#test';
    $(target).focus();
    $(target).val('HELLO').trigger('change');
    $(target).on("change", test($(target).val()));
});

$('#test').on('keypress', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).off("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" value="BUTTON1" />
```

Please check the answer, I hope this will work for you.
I have created a function test, which is called when I `ON` the change event on click function.

Comment: Actually I can't change my text box change function . My keypress event and button click event are written globally and change event is separate for each page. When i type and press enter suggestion will show and clicking suggestion text box value fill completely and change events trigger and load data. If I know the value completely then  type on text box with out enter then data loads. That is I need. But the problems is mine is when i press enter change events work .

Comment: you are changing your textbox change function with `$("#test").on("change", function(){})` which I have placed in the separate function and calling the same on button click, can u please explain in brief what exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: I do have search box in every page to search something like a number and load data corresponds to that number when change the content. I write a function globally that get suggestions on enter key press . Then i clicking on suggestion fill text box and trigger change event. Its working fine. But my need is that when i press enter i don't want trigger change and when i click on suggestion i want to trigger change event. If i have to replace change event then i need to change it on more than 200 places i think